# Error using ==> transpose -- MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, transpose

Im trying to transpose this matrix but its not working ..

Basically I got data such as :

```
s=tf('s')
G=1/(s+1)
[mag phase]=bode(G,1:5)
```

And i get the following for phase :

```
phase(:,:,1) =

   -45


phase(:,:,2) =

  -63.4349


phase(:,:,3) =

  -71.5651


phase(:,:,4) =

  -75.9638


phase(:,:,5) =

  -78.6901
```

Is there a way to put all the values in one column ?

I tried using phase' or phase.'

but I get an error ..

Thanks !

Comment: I'm getting `Undefined function or method 'tf' for input arguments of type 'char'`. But as far as I can see, just doing `phase` should give you everything in a column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `phase=phase(:)` to eliminate the singleton dimensions and organize it as a column vector.

In general, if you have more than one non-singleton dimensions and you only need to remove the singleton dimensions, use `squeeze()`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove extra dimensions from an array, use `squeeze(phase)`.